# My theme.res is 6x bigger than the theme.css it is generated from, is this normal?

Tags: codenameone

My theme.css is 58K, but the generated theme.res (which does not contain any images or fonts, *only* the theme generated from css) is 349K.

Since theme.res is a binary format, and probably more compact than a css text file, this seems strange - has anything changed in the format or could something be wrong in my css file?

If on the other it is normal that the theme.res size can be so much bigger than the theme.css, wouldn't it make sense to add an option to just include the css in the distribution and then generate the theme.res on the device on first run of the application?

Answer (score 0):

58k is huge for a CSS theme so this makes sense. Notice that some CSS styles can't be implemented in Codename Ones styling so the CSS tool launches a browser and grabs a screenshot from the browser then generates an image based on that.

To see if this is what happened just open the resource file using the designer tool and go to the images section to see what images were generated. You can then reverse the styles that triggered image generation and see if you can tune the CSS a bit to avoid image creation.